# Magento customer authentication via API

Tags: java, php, api, magento, soap

I am using Magento with a 3rd party Java Web Application.
My application is "connected" to Magento via Magento SOAP API V2.

How can I perform a Customer Authentication from my Java aplication (outside of Magento) via api?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up to a solution on how to login a customer via SOAP API and I will post it here so it can be helpful for others.Here is what I did to make it work:

1. I created a custom module in Magento with a custom method that login a customer and retuns the **sessionID** that is set on server side.

   ```
   Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($website);
   // Init a Magento session. This is super ultra important
   Mage::getSingleton('core/session'); 

   // $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
   // We get an instance of the customer model for the actual website
   $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
       ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

   // Load the client with the appropriate email
   $customer->loadByEmail($email);

   // Get a customer session
   $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

   $session->loginById($customer->getId());
     if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
       return $session->getSessionId();
   } else {
        return null;
   }
   ```
2. I created a [Magento Custom Api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html) so I can call my login method via SOAP.
3. Call the login method from my JAVA app, get the sessionId, then set the cookies on the browser, based on received sessionId. 
   `http://yourmagentohost/setCookies.php?sessionId=your_session_id`

And inside `setCookies.php` you have: `setcookie("frontend",  $_GET["sessionId"] , time()+3600);`

That's it, now you have a logged in customer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I perform a Customer Authentication from my Java aplication
>   (outside of Magento) via api? SOAP API V2

Clarification: 
API Users (at least Soap) and Customer's are two user types. If you have a pre-existing userlist, and are looking to find out if they exist as user's inside of Magento, you may retrieve email account's and their related attributes and corresponding password hash's (CE: md5:salt , or CE/EE: sha:salt) all via SOAP. If you are looking to do comparative operations, you will need to implement the same Hashing against your password's to do 1:1 comparisons. If you are looking to have your Application use SOAP to directly perform operations, I would make sure that there is a layer of abstraction, as your app could be used nefariously targeting other user id's all depending on the SOAP Role and ACL set in Magento's Admin. 
Moving on...

V2: You'll have to swap to Java, ex: PHP.

```
$username 'yourUsername';

$password = 'yourApiKeyPlainText';

$proxy = new SoapClient('https://www.yourdomain.com/magento/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

$sessionId = $proxy->login($username, $password);

//Get a Full customer List from Magento
$customerList = $proxy->customerCustomerList($sessionId);
//get back a list    

//Target a user from your List, Compare Details against your App
$customerInfo = $proxy->customerCustomerInfo($sessionId, '2'); //Customer Id
```

Remote operations, like Checkout, can be rather involved. The question remains, what do you wish to do next to, or on behalf of the user with your app?

References:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html

Cheers,

Answer (score -2):

Your code example does not use SOAP. Magento SOAP accesses actually look like the following:

```
    $client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/soap/api/?wsdl');

    // If somestuff requires api authentification,
    // then get a session token
    $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

Have a look at the API documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: as is written in your code's comment,it performs an **api authentification**, not a **customer authentification**.

Comment: According to the documentation, there is no call that creates a customer session or sets appropiate cookies, so that the customer is logged in when he/she visits the shop afterwards.